# asp.net mvc jquery removing select list item

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
 $('#remove').click(function() {
        var foo = [];
        $('#FeatureLists :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
            foo[i] = $(selected).text();
            alert(foo[i]);
            if (foo[i] != "Add" )
                return !$('#FeatureLists option:selected').remove();
            if (foo[i] != "Edit")
                return !$('#FeatureLists option:selected').remove();
        });

    });
```

i have six items in my select in which 4 of them are add,edit ,delete view, it is multiselect list, i don't want the user to remove the these 4 items , apart from that they can remove any item. how will i do that? it is not happening in the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, based on your sample code, the array `foo` is does not appear to be needed. Secondly, the if statement needs to include all the items that need to be excluded with `OR` conditions as shown below:

```
if (foo[i] == "Add"    || 
    foo[i] == "Edit"   || 
    foo[i] == "Delete" || 
    foo[i] == "View")
{
     return;             
}
else
{
     $(selected).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as well. Simple one line code and slightly faster

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $("input").click(function(event) {
            var foo = [];
            $('#FeatureLists :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
               foo[i] = $(selected).text();
               if (foo[i] != "Add" && foo[i] != "Edit" && foo[i] != "Delete" && foo[i] != "View") return $(selected).remove();
            });
         });
      });
```